# How should I handle access token and API secrets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, security, access-token, facebook-access-token

Pure android apps use Gradle to handle secure access tokens and API secrets. Where should I store my secrets in Flutter? Is it safe to put them on a text resource file and simply don't commit it?

Comment: I do not quite understand the benefits of app "secrets" (in quotation marks because if they were real secrets they would either not be included in the build or stored server side) being stored in Gradle. Where is your problem of bringing those to Flutter..